# Has anyone used a 1/4" Y adapter and 3.5mm-to-1/4" converter to pipe in music into their aviation headset?

Tags: headset

I have a standard aviation headset and would like to splice in some music for longer flights.  The aviation-specific adapters are overpriced at around $40.  Can i just use a 1/4" Y adapter and a 3.5mm to 1/4" converter, such as these?   Has anyone tried this with results?

https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/YPP118

https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/CMS103

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about electronics, not particularly for aviation (and doesn't need to modify the airplane or the headset).

Comment: The Y adapters are to split outgoing signals, not combine incoming ones. The other problem is that they don't mute on an incoming transmission. If you want to listen to music as you fly, please buy a headset designed for it so you don't miss important communications.

Comment: Also, chances are that the output of your music player is set up for the impedance of a regular audio headset, about 25 ohms, while your aviation headset is likely around 150 ohms.

Comment: @mins could it not be that it is better to ask about an aviation device here rather than elsewhere, where aviators may not be very present?

Comment: @Abdullah: "*could it not be that it is better to ask about an aviation device here rather than elsewhere*" Not my opinion at the time (but this is a vote process, the message appears automatically.) I wasn't followed but I think I was right, it took more than two years to get an answer, and neither the question not the answer have any upvote, meaning nobody is interested, not even you. So asking in the appropriate site would have been better.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about electronics, not particularly for aviation (and doesn't need to modify the airplane or the headset).

Answer (score 0):

Commercial 1/4 Jack audio headsets are stereo, signals to top and ring, body is ground... so you need to fiddle the wires so both signals go to the tip... Else you will.only hear one channel .. I don't advocate this use because if you are listening to.music you might miss calls about other traffic etc.. Your call.